# MediaStyle Notification

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I want to add controls for a media player app to a notification. After some research, i have found that most tutorials used RemoteViews to create a layout for the notification while the official documentation states that RemoteControlClient which was previously been used has been depracated and the Notification.MediaStyle class should be used instead.

All the implementations i have come across of Notification.MediaStyle require a minimum of API 21 to run. I want to know if Notfication.MediaStyle together with MediaSession are backward compatible and can replace RemoteViews during implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think so.

There are [MediaSessionCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) and [NotificationCompat.MediaStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html)

Best regards.

Comment: Great. Let me try it out.

Comment: OK. I hope to help you